# Using time.sleep with selenium (sleep until something is completly loaded)

Tags: python, selenium, time, sleep

i'm trying to find a way, to sleep for as long as it takes for an selenium element to be loaded. i tried it with actionchains and with the inbuilt sleep where you can define a max sleep timeout. However after doing so, it still wasn't what i tried to do (card number got cut off on the first part thus the enterd card number wasn't valid. i then added a 10 seconds time.sleep interval which solved the issue however, sometimes it dosn't work just because it takes more time to load (maybe connection is bad) or the sleep interval is set too high what makes the code unncececary slow.

I expected it to work. I create this code for someone else and this person had the issues with it being too fast while on my side everything went flawlessly.

I don't get any error message it's just a question, how i can implement the sleep within time.sleep for as long as it takes for the element to be fully loaded.

I've tried to use Webdriverwait but this didn't did the thing:

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such Expected Condition to wait until the element to be fully loaded.

I don't know exactly what are you trying to get but most probably the element is loaded in DOM so the expected condition is met even if the content of that element is not there yet.
If you are trying to access a button you can use the `EC.element_to_be_clickable`.

If it is something visible on your screen you can use `EC.visibility_of_element_located`.

The solution here lies in the ExpectedConditions and not in the sleep time which is really random if you will get the content and it will be really slow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you  for the Answer. I tried this `EC.element_to_be_clickable` already however, the issue were the things happen too fast wasn't solved. I'm unsure if the to_be_clickable is usable on input fields too.

Comment: You can increase the delay value if it is still really fast before loading the content. 
I have not tried any expected condition in input field so I am not really sure if element_to_be_clickable is the correct one to use.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. I'll try it when i'm at home and hope, i can mark the Answer as accepted then.